# Latex: In Springer class svjour3, want references sorted in alphabetical order, in author-year format

Tags: latex, bibliography

I am writing a paper in LAtex and using Springer macro package (svjour3 class). 
    Requirement is: citations should be in the form of authoryear and sorted in alphabetical order.

My tex file looks like:

```
{ 

\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\title{abc}


\bibliographystyle{spbasic}      % basic style, author-year citations
%\bibliographystyle{spmpsci}      % mathematics and physical sciences
%\bibliographystyle{apa}   
%bibliographystyle{spphys}       % APS-like style for physics
%\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\bibliography{review}   % name your BibTeX data base


\end{document}
}
```

1. I have used all the possible options of bibliographystyle.
2. Also I have used various types of options in \usepackage[options]{natbib}
3. Tried deleting all the temporary files aux, logs and all others.
4. All entries in bib file have author and year and are separated by commas.

Still I am getting following errors:

```
{
Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations. ...mmand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers
}
```

Comment: I have tried all the methods and read many pages online but still cannot solve the same issue...

Answer (score 3):

You have to add:

```
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
```

and then add bibliography as:

```
\bibliographystyle{spbasic} 
\bibliography{sample.bib}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You have to add:
>
> `\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}`
>
> and then add bibliography as:
>
> `\bibliographystyle{spbasic}`
> `\bibliography{sample.bib}`

That almost did it for me. I changed it to

```
    \usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}
```

in the preamble. Cited with

```
    \citep{ReferenceXY}
```

and added my bib

```
    \bibliographystyle{spbasic} 
    \bibliography{literature.bib}
```